# How to balance a one page RPG that has three scores?

Tags: balance, dice, game-design, darkshire-three-score-rpg

I recently saw a great little one page RPG called Potatoes shared by [*Death by Badgers* on twitter](https://twitter.com/deathbybadger/status/1567425842526945280):

> Potato, a one page RPG about being a halfling and trying to quietly enjoy your potatoes in a world that refuses to leave you alone

[image: Rules for the one-page RPG called 'Potatoes']

I won't try to transcribe the rules here, but I'm always fascinated by the balance of these games, where you *have three scores, and you race one against the other two*.

You can estimate the expected ratio of each score (Orc, Potato and Destiny) per roll fairly easily as "In the garden..." and "Knock at the door" are equally likely, by adding up the pluses and minuses for each potential result: +3 potato, +5 destiny, +6 orc.

Someone also made a simulation in python and [posted the results in that twitter thread](https://twitter.com/OrenBern/status/1567508078110687236):

> Potato hibernation: 22.1%
> Eaten by orcs: 54.6%
> Called to adventure: 23.3%

The 'hurling in the back garden' mechanic is inspired, and adds a twist but I don't think that's necessary to balance the game.

I've also seen one-page RPGs where the whole point was, because the balance was shifted so that you could never win, to make social commentary (which it's worth adding, the author has explicitly said, was not the point of Potato).

---

Now I full endorse *Death By Badgers* sentiment that:

> the pursuit of excellence is a self-imposed shackle and I refuse to be burdened by it

But despite myself I'm still fascinated by the balance of these games, and how to use that to get a certain 'feeling' from these games. My gut feeling is to somehow make the ratio of scores close so that the random rolls make winning possible but not guaranteed, but not so close that you need a very long game over which they balance out.

But how does one strike that balance when trying to elicit certain emotions? Is it purely trial and error to make a 'hard but winnable' game vs. 'obviously impossible' game? How can you balance one of these where winning is more likely than not, but still feels worthwhile to play - instead of a forgone conclusion?

If you look at [Trapped in a Cabin with Lord Byron](https://boingboing.net/2022/03/29/play-trapped-in-a-cabin-with-lord-byron-the-one-page-rpg.html) it's essentially the same game, but with wildly different outcomes - this feels like it would make it more bleak but how does one make sure it's not a boring game that's impossible?

I feel like someone with experience making these sort of games could distil down their process into a 'good subjective' answer that covers how they achieve feeling through the balance they aim for.

Comment: If I understood the question well, as something like "what's a formula or method to balance any one-page RPG?", I'm afraid the question might be either too broad or unanswerable. Balance is usually something you take case-by-case, depending on each system's mechanics and how they interact with each others. Then again, I might have missed the point of the question, in which case it could benefit from clarifications.

Comment: This claims to be a RPG, but where is the R here? This is just rolling dice with no decision making involved at all, until the random event generator reaches one of the end states. It is dressed up in fantasy trappings, but does that make it an RPG? (Talking about the game, not your question).

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin: Where's the R in any solo RPG? In the player's head, arguably. Which, of course, is where it is in any RPG — with nobody else playing there just isn't anyone else to tell you "come on, roleplay it just a little, will you?" except yourself.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I can see the "hurling" maybe introducing some kind of decision, although one could use a heuristic to use it 9 ORC and if there are less then 9 POTATOs left. I think solo RPGs are different a lot, normally you can choose a lot of different paths consciously, making decisions. I concur you are not playing a character role in either case.

Comment: This looks well-scoped and clearly in our area of expertise. Vtlo.

Comment: I think the game image you presented has a typo. It appears that 10 orcs is the intended number for "if your Orcs score ..." entry.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the game presented isn't an RPG.  It's a fun solo game about a hobbit trying to avoid the world.

Comment: Whether or not *Potatoes* is an RPG is the least of this question's problems. This question is just unanswerable because it is far too general.

Comment: "*How can you balance one of these where winning is more likely than not, but still feels emotionally fulfilling to play - instead of a forgone conclusion?*" seems like a clear and objectively answerable question to me. (Well, maybe not objectively for the "emotionally fulfilling" part, but that seems ignorable.)

Comment: @From I'd have expected that either the Orc and Destiny would have the same percentage, or that 'eaten by orcs' would be much lower as that's the only negative score you can reduce.

Comment: I think it would be better to present a system and ask "does this proposed system balance in the way I intend it to." This does seem too general, even if it is technically answerable by someone who has designed every type of 1-page RPG.

Comment: There does not seem any R or G in this, since the player has no agency in either. I am not sure how "watching a scripted event unfold based on random dice rolls" is "played" either. It can be observed. There is exactly *one* decision to be made here: at 8/8 Potatoes/Orcs, do I trade or do I risk it. That decision can be made beforehand and then you can have a coffee while you observe the results. I would not call that a "game" or "roleplaying".

Answer (score 6):

You've asked:

> How can you balance one of these where winning is more likely than not, but still feels worthwhile to play?

and unfortunately I think there's a wrong assumption here.

In games, replay value comes from *interesting choices* and *new experiences*.  This game has hardly any choices, so all the replay value is coming from the experience it offers -- specifically, the flavor text about being a halfling who doesn't want to go on an adventure.  The actual win probability is not important.

(My suspicion is that few people actually play this game, and hardly anybody plays it more than once, simply because a read-through allows the player to experience everything the game has to offer.  In some sense we might view "Potato" as more of an art-form-in-the-shape-of-a-game than an actual playable activity.)

So, many people will feel that games of this sort are not worthwhile to actually play.  But those who do play it will be playing it because of the interesting flavor text.  So my advice is to focus on the flavor text and not on the game mechanics.

---

If you do want to tune the probabilities, it's best to write a simulator (or borrow someone else's) and run it to find out what probabilities any game configuration gives you.

Comment: You make an interesting point! Do you have anything to back this up?